# Is there a better way of making sure a variable only contains numbers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

```
toss_number = input("How many times do you want to toss the coin?\n")

while True:
    if toss_number.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        toss_number = input("Please input NUMBER of times you want to toss a coin.\n")
```

These lines of code essentially make sure that toss_number contains a string of numbers. Is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Other ways to approach this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way is to use `try` / `except`. This will be more efficient if, more often than not, a number is input.

```
while True:
    try:
        toss_number = int(input("How many times do you want to toss the coin?\n"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You have not entered a NUMBER.')
```

When `ValueError` is raised, a message is printed, but the loop is not broken, so we return to beginning of the `while` loop and the `try` section.

Comment: Why are we able to put `break` before `except ValueError`?

Comment: I just thought that you would want to put the break after `except ValueError`, or add an `else: break` statement to the end of the while statement.

Comment: So is the fact that a `ValueError` is raised, prevent `break` from breaking the while loop?